# how can I make droplets placed on a cup properly?

Tags: modeling, particles

I am trying to achieve a scene where a cup of glass covered with droplets. I'm using particles system and a group of droplets from separate layer, to make it possible, but I can't get droplets appear with correct direction. I was wondering what kind of settings should be done to fix this problem, please see the screenshots below

[image: false oriented droplets]
[image: droplets group]
[image: particles]

- I have tried changing the positions of each droplets in the group, but didn't work
- I have tried changing the rotations under the particles but couldn't reach a good result

thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply @gandalf3 ,I have tried to change things according to questions you directed above, finally I can get the droplets in correct direction but this time they are not covering the surface properly as shown below https://www.evernote.com/shard/s96/sh/a5e33412-1c30-480f-b85b-48efbe79d611/d5d0d90560d497c8d568e3d402231f21/deep/0/GLASS-DROPS.blend.png  sorry for if I skipped something which has already mentioned but I really cant figure out what causing the problem and how to fix it

Comment: Try using *Velocity/Hair* as the initial rotation. If that doesn't work, is it possible you could upload the file?

Comment: ok, tried the velocity/hair but it didn't work either, i'm sending the file, can you have a look at it please? thanks http://we.tl/3PZ39DCGHj

Comment: Ah, remember that when *rotation* is enabled in *particle settings > render* the objects should be aligned with `+X` (yes, it's weird like that). If I rotate the droplet objects 90 degrees on the Z it works as expected.

Comment: YES! :) that worked, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: just one more thing which  i realised when going top view, the droplets ( particles) are spread out only the half of the cup which is facing the camera, the other half there's no particular, is this normal?

Comment: That's because you specified a vertex group for the particles to go on, however it only covers half the cup. Switch to edit mode  and press *Select* in *Properties > Object Data (inverted triangle icon) > Vertex groups* to see what vertices are in the vertex group. Select more vertices and press *Assign* to add them to the group.

Comment: thanks a lot again, its all fine now , appreciate taking your time helping me out, Bests